# Drunken Man in Matlab

Tags: matlab, algorithms

I wrote a script that plots the results of the "drunken lamppost" problem in MATLAB. 
Now I need to create a road-width from -3 to +3, length from 0 to infinity but the drunk can walk just ahead. It means that when he reaches the road's edge MATLAB will automatically stop plotting.

My code is here:

```
r=[0 0];
for t= 0:0.1:100 
    B1=rand(1,2);
    B=B1>0.5;
    if B==1
        rnew=r+[0 1];

    elseif B(1)==1
        rnew=r+[-1 1];

    elseif B(2)==1
        rnew=r+[1 1];
    end

    hold on;
    plot([r(1) rnew(1)],[r(2) rnew(2)]);
    drawnow ;
    r=rnew;
end
```

[image]

Comment: Cant you just insert an if statement? You know his cartesian x-y coordinates from the rnew vector, so it seems like you could just check with an if statement whether rnew is outside [-3,3].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already handing every step individually, so as @user2697246 says in the comment you can simply add an if statement checking for your condition, and a break.

In other words add this right before the `end` for your `for` loop:

```
if ((rnew(2) < -3) || (rnew(2) > 3))
    break;
end
```

I do have a comment about your first conditional, `B==1`.  `B` is a logical matrix, and I can't find in the documentation how matlab handles this.  Please make sure this is doing what you think it is, and consider rewriting it if you can find a better way to express your logic.